# Restoring a Team site collection inside another environment will display an empty white page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, deployment, backup, restore

I have developed a team site inside my development machine, which contains the following :-

1. 5 overlayed calendar Apps.
2. One announcement APP
3. One document management APP
4. Script editor web part
5. Content editor web part
6. APP parts for displaying the overlayed calenders, announcement and the document management APPs

I did the following:-

1. I backup the team site collection, using the administration UI inside my development machine.
2. I copy the backup file to the staging environment.
3. I have created a team site on the following URL :- staging01:12160/sites/Intranet .
4. I use the following command to restore the site collection to my staging environment (staging01)

   Restore-spsite -identity staging01:12160/sites/Intranet  -path C:\Users\username\Desktop\intra –force
5. After doing the restore I tried to access the team site on  staging01:12160/sites/Intranet  . but I will be prompted to enter the username and password, after that an empty white page will be displayed. Baring in mind that I tried to restore the same back up file on the development machine and it worked well. And I have restored a community site collection on my staging environment and it worked well.

So can anyone advice on what might be wrong with restoring my team site collection inside my staging environment ?
Thanks a lot for any help, as I need to move my site collection to the staging environment ASAP.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You should use the restore command as follow: 
`Restore-SPSite http://server_name/sites/site_name -Path C:\Backup\site_name.bak`

All site collection features that are Activated on the dev machine needs to be active on the staging machine.

Regards,
JP

Comment: and this what i already did ?

Comment: and when i backup a site collection from the admin UI (backup and Restore --> Perform a site collection backup), it will generate a file but without a .bak extension. can you advice ?

Comment: You can simply modify the file being generated by the SP UI, and add a .bak extension to it.
Rather Use this command to backup from power shell:
`Backup-SPSite http://server_name/sites/site_name -Path C:\Backup\site_name.bak`
and restore using the command previously provided, this should work.

Comment: i tried you poer shell command but i m getting the following exception :- Restore-SPSite : <nativehr>0x80070003</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>
At line:1 char:1
+ Restore-SPSite http://tstaging01:12160/sites/Intranet -Path
C:\Users\user ...

Comment: You need to specify the http:// in front of you server name

Comment: yes i already added the http:// !!! . my command looks as follow:-Restore-SPSite http://tstaging01:12160/Sites/Intranet   -Path C:\Users\user\Desktop\Backup\Intranet.bak

Comment: but this forum will trim the http:// inside my commnet :)

Comment: Yeah, I saw that a little to late, are you running your powershell as administrator?

Comment: yes i am running the powershell as admin ? and i am login to the sharepoint using a managed account